# vb.net play a sound without using windows media player

Tags: vb.net, audio

is there a way to play a sound in vb.net without using windows media player.

I have tried my.computer.audio.play but this appears to do nothing.
and I have tried axshockwaveflash.loadmovie(couldnt find an audio).play

I cant seem to find another alternative does anyone have any surggestions please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using My.Computer.Audio.Play() should work - have you tried passing in the full (absolute) filename of a WAV file to see if this works.  You can also have a look at this CodeProject article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/soundplayerbug.aspx if you want to try another way of playing sound, although it shouldn't be necessary to go to these lengths unless you are experiencing the problem mentioned in the article.

Comment: `My.Computer.Audio.Play()` only supports WAV files, so you may have to look at referencing Media Player: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337110/how-to-play-mp3-file-from-resources-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If you have a swish-max software, all you have to do is open its environment then create a script by clicking on the add script button at the left esteem, choose sound and select play sound method. in the script environment click on import to choose a sound . then click on sound property, activate the " don't play again while playing is on", then reduce the volume rate play it again and click Ok button.

In your project, create an instance of shock_wave object, right click on it to access its property, on its Movie property, specify the path of the movie created in the swish_max
then run your program.

or

if you don't want to do it in design, you create a button name play and add the following code under it

private sub buttonPlay_Click(Byval sender as object , Byval e as sysyem.eventArgs) handles _bttonplay.click

Axtshockwave1.movie="put the path of your movie here quoting it"

end sub

Answer (score 0):

I want to avoid adding any additional dll dependencies to the project,
so my work around for now, is to call
Process.run(file);

as this calls windows own shell and runs the program if any program exists to run it, if not it gives the user the option to do whatever they want with it.